# Line Integral through diagram

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Can someone let me know what is going on in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#/media/File:Line_integral_of_scalar_field.gif) figure in simple terms? I think that this is awesome explanation of line integral, but I can't understand what $|r'(t)|$ is doing there except [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Derivation) where its existence is attributed to mean value theorem. Is there a more direct explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ds$ in the left-hand integral represents an element of length along the curve. The $|{\bf r}^\prime(t)|$ could be thought of as the speed of motion along the curve, and therefore $|{\bf r}^\prime(t)|\,dt$ could be thought of as "speed times time," or length, which is why $|{\bf r}^\prime(t)|\,dt$ corresponds with $ds$.

Note: ${\bf r}(t)$ is a vector, and so is ${\bf r}^\prime(t)$. The quantity $|{\bf r}^\prime(t)|$ is the length of the velocity vector, that is, the speed.